# Vue Component - How to handle non-reactive data?

Tags: vue.js

I'm losing track of reactivity overhead best practices in a Vue 2 Component. I need to generate a one time string with genId() and assign it to the component' id attribute. It seems like overkill to have any watching going on after that.

1. Is `:id="myID"` the right way to insert this into the html id?

And then when setting up the source where do I put the non-reactive data? I had 3 thoughts:

1. Add property `myID: genId()` to `data`. But doesn't that add it to the watchlist automatically even though it won't change? Causing overhead?
2. I read on [Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/extracting-business-logic-away-components-reactive-data-from-non-reactive-data/21656/7?u=nathaniel-rink) from a year old answer that `myID: genId()` should go in the `created` hook. Are using hooks for this kind of thing a best practice? I thought hooks were discouraged.
3. Or I could put it in the component `methods` and then call it directly with `:id="genId()`

Is there a **Vue** way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use method 2 for non-reactive data *(and you use that component many many times on the page that the small overhead of adding the change listeners has any impact.)*

```
created() {
  this.myId = genId()
}
```

The 3 methods behave differently:

**Method 1: data**
This will call the genId() when the data object is created and add change listeners.

**Method 2: created hook**
This will call the genId() when the component object is created and doesn't add change listeners.

**Method 3: method**
This will call the genId() every time the template re-renders. Which happens every time a change is detected on a variable the view is listening to or a `$forceUpdate()` is called.

Ps. Vue objects already have a unique id: `this._uid`
*but this is a private property and might change in a future version of Vue.*

Comment: Thank you very much!! I knew about `this._uid` but in all the documentation I can find they advise against using it since it's a private property and they aren't committed to supporting it moving forward?